# Google Analytics not building for 64 bit architecture (v 3.03)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, 64-bit

I've read on the release notes that Google Analytics V 3.03 is compatible with 64 bit apps on iOS. I added it to my project per the getting started guide and I am getting this:

[image]

Since I cannot find much on google (ironic, I know) on how to troubleshoot the issue, and it says it is ready for 64 bit - I am assuming I am doing something wrong. Does anybody have any advice on things I can look for or that I may doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to add the libz.dylib framework to get that error to go away.

Comment: You were right....I thought I had it added in the build settings already and I did not. This fixed. Will accept when SO lets me.